# How to have plotly subplot subtitles with a multi-line main title?

Tags: python, plotly

Consider the following python code:

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = make_subplots(
    rows=2, cols=1,
    subplot_titles=("Plot 1", "Plot 2"))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[4, 5, 6]),
              row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[300, 400, 500], y=[600, 700, 800]),
              row=2, col=1)
title_text = "Multiple Subplots with Titles<br>Multiple Subplots with Titles<br>Multiple Subplots with Titles<br>Multiple Subplots with Titles<br>Multiple Subplots with Titles"

fig.update_layout(title_text=title_text, title_x=0.5)
fig.show()
```

which generates:
[image]

How do I push all the subplots down to make room for the multi-line main title as well as the subtitle of the first subplot?

Comment: Maximize the position of the y-axis in the title, increase the margin, and increase the vertical of the graph size. `fig.update_layout(title_text=title_text, title_x=0.5, title_y=1.0, margin=dict(t=110), height=400)`

Comment: Does not work -- chops off top of title.

Comment: My comments are environmentally dependent, so make sure the margins and graph height are appropriate for your environment.

Comment: Parameters need to be adjusted as a function of the number of lines in the title, which is a bummer....